# Python "self" is not defined in function arguments list

Tags: python, self

Is there any way to do the following?

```
def getTables(self, db = self._dbName):
    //do stuff with db    
    return func(db)
```

I get a `"self" is not defined`. I could do this...

```
def getTables(self, db = None):
    if db is None:
        db = self._db
    //do stuff with db
    return func(db)
```

... but that is just annoying.

Comment: Are these stand-alone functions or methods?

Comment: You want to set a default value for an argument based on other arguments?

Comment: the correct way to do it is: def getTables(self, db = None):

Comment: Short answer: no. `None` is the correct default here. `self` doesn't exist until *inside* the method.

Comment: @Dylan - [looks to me like you understood my comment :P](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143268/python-self-is-not-defined-in-function-arguments-list#comment39138718_25143268)

Comment: It doesn't match selected answer below...

Comment: It's a consequence of the answer. The answer explains *why* that is, but that doesn't make jon's assertion untrue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function signatures are evaluated *when the function is defined*, not when the function is called.

When the function is being defined there are no instances yet, there isn't even a *class* yet.

To be precise: the expressions for a class body are executed before the class object is created. The expressions for function defaults are executed before the function object is created. At that point, you cannot create an instance to bind `self` to.

As such, using a sentinel (like `None`) is really your only option. If `db` is never falsey you can simply use:

```
def getTables(self, db=None):
    db = db or self._db
```

Comment: +1 -- a much better answer than mine, since understanding this is important to understanding (for instance) why `def foo(bar={})` is Evil And Wrong (sharing a single, mutable `{}` object, rather than creating a new dict on every call).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this onle-liner version will be slightly less "annoying":

```
def getTables( self, db = None):
    db = self._db if db is None else db
    ...
```

You simply can not set a default value for an argument based upon the value of a another argument because the argument you want to base your default value on hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: I just don't want the if statement in general. I want it in the function parameters list

Comment: @Dylan - ah yes... but what about what the *python* interpreter wants? ;)